# REGEX to find words containing permutations of letters, with one letter mandatory, and NOT any other

Tags: mysql, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

We have a mysql table with a column that has alphanumeric text. We have a unique use case where we need to find every row in the table where this column has text that contains:

- One letter for sure, say S
- Plus one or more of a few other letters, say T, A, C, N (the letters can be in an order, and repeated as many times)
- NOT contain any other letters other  than the S and the T, A, C, N

As such, these would be OK:

```
SCAN
SCATTCC
NCAS 
NTTAAS
```

These would NOT be OK:

```
CATI     (does not contain S, and contains I which is outside of S, T, C, A, N) 
SCANNF   (contains F which is outside of S, T, C, A, N) 
NCASO    (contains O which is outside of S, T, C, A, N) 
..
```

We tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
[tacn]*[s]+(?![^stacn])+
```

Comment: To my knowledge, negative look-ahead are not supported in MySQL, but even if it did, applying a repetition operator to a zero-width look-ahead construct does not make sense.  The look-ahead construct does not advance the string position, so to apply it multiple times would just be spinning the wheels.  Even if it did support the look-ahead, it seems like that particular pattern should have undefined behavior.

Comment: It's not clear whether `S` could appear multiple times or not.  Is `SCANS` or `NSCAS` okay?

Comment: Sounds to me like [`^[TACN]*[S][STACN]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/GJy2j7/1/)

Comment: @bobblebubble  That does not satisfy the "one or more" condition of the other letters.  Your pattern matches a string of only `S`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MySQL 8.0.4+**

From MySQL 8.0.4 onwards, [MySQL regexp support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) changed to the ICU library, and lookaheads are supported. For those versions, this regex will meet your requirements:

```
'^(?=.*s)(?=.*[acnt])(?!.*[^acnst])'
```

It uses 3 lookaheads:

1. `(?=.*s)` asserts there is an `S` in the string;
2. `(?=.*[acnt])` asserts there is at least one of `[ACNT]` in the string;
3. `(?!.*[^acnst])` asserts that there are no characters other than `[ACNST]` in the string.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3b26850593227657c6fbc231eea4281)

**MySQL prior to 8.0.4**

This regex will give you the results you want:

```
^[tacn]*(s[cant]|[tacn]s)[cant]*$
```

It looks for either

- an `S` preceded by zero or more of `[TACN]` and followed by one or more of `[TACN]`; or
- an `S` preceded by one or more of `[TACN]` and followed by zero or more of `[TACN]`

Query:

```
SELECT str, 
       str REGEXP '^[tacn]*(s[cant]|[tacn]s)[cant]*$' AS `match`
FROM test
```

Output:

```
str     match
SCAN    1
SCATTCC 1
NCAS    1
NTTAAS  1
CATI    0
SCANNF  0
NCASO   0
CANT    0
S       0
SS      0
TS      1
SC      1
STS     0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6dc34e9a0a7115b888a700382a60c347)

If you want to allow `S` to occur more than once, just change the regex to

```
^[stacn]*(s[cant]|[tacn]s)[scant]*$
```

This changes the result for `STS` to `1`, while leaving the result for `SS` as `0` since it doesn't contain a character other than `S`.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=835f04409c5366573a86a08f67e8f4c8)

Comment: Thank you for the patient and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

This assumes that `s` can appear multiple times just like the other allowed characters.  The requirements do not explicitly exclude that possibility although the examples do not include such an example.  I do not interpret "One letter for sure" to mean "appears only once".

```
^(s+[tacn][stacn]*|[tacn]+s[stacn]*)$
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, `S` can repeat as well. Your code doesn't seem to work though. It finds no records.

Comment: Strange, since when I plug my pattern into Nick's dbfiddle (the same answer that you accepted) I get precisely the same results.  I tested it and it works fine.  I think that maybe you're not copy and pasting it correctly.  I did not spoon feed all details like Nick, but it should work fine if implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex for pattern matching :

```
pattern = "^(S+[TACN]+S*[TACN]*)+$|^(S*[TACN]+S+[TACN]*)+$"
```

Comment: This is not consistent.  It matches `ncsans` but not `scans`.  This implies that if an S reappears at all that it must reappear at the beginning or end of the sequence in the same order as the first match.  In other words, it is enforcing an unnecessary restriction on the pattern.

Comment: For multiple S situation: this pattern will do the trick, please check :  pattern="^(S+[TACN]+S*)+$|^(S*[TACN]+S+)+$" . Updated the ans above as well

Comment: This still fails to match the case with `s` embedded within a valid string but not on the ends, like `ANSTC`.

Comment: nice catch. Updated the regex pattern :  pattern = "^(S+[TACN]+S*[TACN]*)+$|^(S*[TACN]+S+[TACN]*)+$"